# Excel VBA copy multiple lines

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy some data from one Sheet to another using a vba script, it works fine but it doesn't appear to gather all the results, the data i have is split up over multiple tables so i assume it's seeing a blank space and stepping out but i'm not sure the solution! (the results i'm after are all letters i.e A-f and are all located on column C)

code below:

```
Sub copytoprint()
   Dim LSearchRow As Integer
   Dim LCopyToRow As Integer
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   On Error GoTo Err_Execute

   LSearchRow = 2
   LCopyToRow = 2

   While Len(Range("C" & CStr(LSearchRow)).value) > 0
     If InStr(1, Range("C" & CStr(LSearchRow)).value, "A") > 0 Then
         Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
         Selection.Copy
              
         Sheets("dest").Select
         Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste

         LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1
         Sheets("source").Select

      End If

      LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

   Wend

   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Range("A3").Select

   MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

   Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
   MsgBox "An error occurred."

End Sub
```

Input would just be a basic line of details i.e

```
ID      person  ref itemid  itemname        shape
Alphas1 bob     A   As01    Alphaselects1   circle
Alphas2 Stuart  B   As02    Alphaselects2   circle
```

Basically they are split up with many records I'd like it to grab all the A reference put them in one table then folow on with B C etc

Hope that makes a little sense?

Comment: Explain your desired input and output , It's not clear !

Comment: Hi There, added a bit more information! basically want it to look the same just on a difference sheet with them all in 1 table instead of many!

Comment: Perhaps disable your error handling until everything's working properly.    Also, are you able to describe line by line what your code is doing?   Might be a good idea to check out the [tour] as well as [ask] and [mcve].  _Welcome!_

Comment: I think you can remove a lot of confusion if you don't use `.Range("A" & y & ":Z" & y)` type of references and use `.Range("A2").Cells(i,j)` or better yet set entire tables with one move with `.Range("A2").Resize(10,2).Value = ..` type of constructs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to search from ActiveSheet using certain reference (A,B,C,,etc) and copy matching rows into unique destination sheets.
Below code will help you accomplish this, it separates the copying sub-procedure out into its own sub (called copyToSheet) and you can keep calling it from copytoprint() each time giving a reference and the destination sheet you desire.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub copyToSheet(reference As String, shtSource As Worksheet, shtDest As Worksheet)
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    shtDest.Range("A2:Z" & shtDest.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 2).ClearContents
    x = 2
    y = 2
    'loop until 20 consequtive rows have column C blank
    While (Not shtSource.Range("C" & x).Value = "") _
        And (Not shtSource.Range("C" & (x + 1)).Value = "") _
        And (Not shtSource.Range("C" & (x + 5)).Value = "") _
        And (Not shtSource.Range("C" & (x + 10)).Value = "") _
        And (Not shtSource.Range("C" & (x + 20)).Value = "")

        'If shtSource.Range("C" & x).Value, reference) > 0 Then
        If shtSource.Range("C" & x).Value = reference Then
            shtDest.Range("A" & y & ":Z" & y).Value = shtSource.Range("A" & x & ":Z" & x).Value
            y = y + 1
        End If
        x = x + 1
    Wend
End Sub
Public Sub copytoprint()
    copyToSheet "A", ActiveSheet, Sheets("A")
    copyToSheet "B", ActiveSheet, Sheets("B")
    MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi There, thanks for that! I still seem to be getting the error where it won't pick up any B,C,D values etc, I believe it is because there is a gap between the tables so it thinks that there is no results? is there a method of searching x amount of rows down before it believes its completed?  thanks again!

Comment: Yes. Change the loop check from
    While Not shtSource.Range("C" & x).Value = ""
to
    While (Not shtSource.Range("C" & x).Value = "") And (Not shtSource.Range("C" & (x + 1)).Value = "") And  (Not shtSource.Range("C" & (x + 5)).Value = "") And  (Not shtSource.Range("C" & (x + 10)).Value = "") And (Not shtSource.Range("C" & (x + 20)).Value = "")

Comment: Hi Steve, Thanks for that! I can't seem to get this working i don't suppose you could show it in the example you posted? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood your problem correctly then you want to sort the data in sheet source first and then paste all of that data in another sheet.

If that's the case try this code.

```
Sub copytoprint()

    Dim lastrow As Double

    With Sheets("source")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A2:F" & lastrow).Sort key1:=Range("C3:C" & lastrow), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
    End With

    Sheets("dest").Range("A2:F" & lastrow).Value = Sheets("source").Range("A2:F" & lastrow).Value


End Sub
```