# Search Range looking for multiple terms then proceed

Tags: vba, excel

I am having an issue with with a section of my coding.  I am trying to have a macro search row 1 for a term and if found then offset one cell and select over to column F.  My issue is that I can only have it search for one term.  I have to open up the VBA window and change the word if I want it to search for the second word.  I would like it to search for either term and then offset based on the first occurrence in Row ("1:1").  Here is what I have.  I need it to also look for the word "Mat".

```
Rows("1:1").Select
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
Set SrchRng = Range("1:1")
For Each cel In SrchRng
   If InStr(1, cel.Value, "Units per Assy") > 0 Then
        cel.Offset(0, -1).Select
   End If
Next cel
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), Cells(Selection.Row, 6)).Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Select
```

Comment: You mean something like `If InStr(1, cel.Value, "Units per Assy") > 0 And InStr(1, cel.Value, "Mat") > 0 Then` ?

Comment: @ShaiRado You beat me to it. :)

Comment: This one seems to be looking for both values in the same cell.  These terms would be in separate cells, and I need it to move to the then statement based on the first occurance.

Answer (score 3):

Why not add another condition like below?

```
If InStr(1, cel.Value, "Units per Assy") > 0 Or InStr(1, cel.Value, "Mat") > 0 Then
```

Comment: But you were typing the whole answer :)

Comment: This piece is finding the first term "Mat" but then it still moves on to look for the next term.  I need it to move directly to the then statement and finish the offset and column select.  Thanks...its getting closer.

Comment: Maybe you need Exit For just below the line where it offsets and select the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to understand why you use Range.Select() on many cells.
Anyways to search from a list of words you can adopt you code as below.

```
'Assume you search words are on a hidden sheet called 'Search Strings' from 
'range A1:A5

Option Explicit
Public Sub highlight()
    Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
    Dim searchStringsRange As Range, celSearch As Range
    Set SrchRng = Range("1:1")
    Set searchStringsRange = Sheets("Search Strings").Range("A1:A5")
    'SrchRng.Select
    For Each cel In SrchRng
        For Each celSearch In searchStringsRange
            If InStr(1, cel.Value, celSearch.Value) > 0 Then
                 cel.Offset(0, -1).Select
                 Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next cel
    'Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), Cells(Selection.Row, 6)).Select
    'Selection.EntireColumn.Select
End Sub
```

Hope above helps, it will select only one cell using offset. 
Give me details on how you want to highlighting/selecting done

Comment: I don't have to use range.select.  the cel.offset select would work as long as no matter where it finds the search string, it then offsets and selects over to column F.

Comment: The entire column select piece is due to blank rows in the data of those columns.

Comment: You are searching across rows (1:1) and highlighting a column (F:F). This is a bit confusing for me, i would expect you to high the matching cells on another row eg (2:2).

Comment: The first part of the data always starts in column F.  The term that it searches for in Row (1:1), starts the next set of data.  So when it finds the term "Mat" or "Units per Assy" I need it to then offset one column and select from that column over to column F.

Comment: Please share a sample of the data

Comment: Do tab seperated text. eg this guy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47413071/excel-vba-copy-multiple-lines/47415830?noredirect=1#comment81786302_47415830

Comment: Problem solved.  I had to fix the exit out of the loop once the first term was found.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.  After sktneer's answer, I needed to add an exit for statement.  works perfectly now.  Below is the updated code.

Rows("1:1").Select
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
Set SrchRng = Range("1:1")
For Each cel In SrchRng
If InStr(1, cel.Value, "Mat") > 0 Or InStr(1, cel.Value, "Units per Assy") > 0 Then
        cel.Offset(0, -1).Select
        Exit For
   End If
Next cel
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), Cells(Selection.Row, 6)).Select